# Using variables to call on [database].[schema]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to manipulate this existing code as whilst testing, it doesn't reference to the exact location of a table. What I mean by this is that it does not reference the table's database name and schema along with its table name. Example: if the table is called `'package'`, then at the moment it just outputs in the update statement 'package' and not `'Holidays.dbo.package'`. `Holidays` is obviously the database name.

But here is the issue, which table I am referring to may not be in the just the `Holidays` database, it could come from other database or schemas for that matter. So I can't simply add `update 'Holidays.dbo.' + @tablename`, I need it to be more dynamic than that.

My question is if I set two variables to call the database and schema, how can I set the variables to refer to them?

Below is parts of the code I extracted that I believe is relevant to this issue:

```
declare @tablename varchar(MAX)
declare @loop int = 1           

select  a.* into #tmp
from 
(
select  RID,
v.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  'Field', 
v.value('./text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   'Value'        
from  #XMLTemp
cross apply Field.nodes ('/Record/*') x(v)
where v.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  not in ('Update', 'Filter', 'Insert', 'Delete')
) as a
where RID = @loop

...

select @tablename = ''
select @tablename = Value
from #tmp
where Field='tableName'
and RID = @loop

...

print 'update ' + @tablename + '

...

select @tablename = Value from #tmp where Field = 'TableName'

...

set @loop = @loop+1
```

**UPDATE:**

Below is the xml for the 'ProductPerson' table with the new value entered and its previous value.

```
<Task xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Record>
    <order>1</order>
    <TableName>ProductPerson</TableName>
    <KeyField>ProductPersonID</KeyField>
    <TableRef>32420</TableRef>
    <Update>
      <FieldName>StatusID</FieldName>
      <OldValue>3</OldValue>
      <NewValue>8</NewValue>
    </Update>
  </Record>
</Task>
```

Below is how the xml is generated:

```
BEGIN
-- Get details of any changes made
-- First are any update fragments stored
-- (basically these are the data changes)
select 
z.value('(./FieldName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   'FieldName',
z.value('(./OldValue/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')    'OldValue',
z.value('(./NewValue/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')    'NewValue',
'Update' [Type]
into #Changes
from #XMLTemp t
cross apply field.nodes('/Record/*') y(z)
where z.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') = 'Update'
and RID = @loop
UNION ALL
-- Now get any Filter changes (from addnlfragment)
-- These aren't data changes but are used for filtering.
select 
z.value('(./FieldName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   'FieldName',
'' [OldValue],
z.value('(./FilterValue/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')     'NewValue',
'Filter' [Type]
from #XMLTemp t
cross apply field.nodes('/Record/*') y(z)
where z.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') = 'Filter'
and RID = @loop

-- Only consider "update" types here - as filters may have blank old values for a specific field
set @update = ''
SELECT   @update = COALESCE(@update , '') + 
FieldName + iif (isnull(OldValue, 'NUL') = 'NUL', ' = ' +isnull(OldValue, 'NULL') + ',' ,  ' = ''' +isnull(OldValue, ' NULL ') +''',')
FROM    #Changes
where Type ='Update'                        

-- Remove any extra commas from the end of the generated string
if(RIGHT(@update, 1) = ',')
BEGIN
set @update = substring(@update, 1, len(@update)-1)
END
```

Comment: Could you paste the XML (or relevant part of it)? I've got the feeling that there might be a better approach...

Comment: @Shnugo, Sorry for lateness, I was in a meeting, I havei ncluded the code above in an update

Comment: Hi, no problem, thx for the XML. Will this be always "one solid statement" or might there be several statements packed in one Taks (or Record)? Do I understand you correctly, that you want to perform the action of the task against your database? How do the XMLs look like in case of other CRUD operations?

Comment: It will always be one solid statement. Virtually the issue that when we copy and past the printed update statement into a new query, we have to always type in the db and schema individually before the table name, but if we can get this automatically printed instead, then sorted.

Comment: **Usually** this sort of thing is solved at the application framework level, because you don't really want to manage connections yourself.  You get a cached connection to a database (which often has a preset schema lookup path), so you never have to specify the database/schema yourself.  You can, and there's times when you have to, but it's usually unnecessary.  Dynamic SQL should generally be avoided, as it's a great way to get hit with SQL Injection.  If you do need to do dynamic table names, verify they exist before running the statement (will limit many shenanigans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
declare @x  xml=
'<Task xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Record>
    <order>1</order>
    <TableName>ProductPerson</TableName>
    <KeyField>ProductPersonID</KeyField>
    <TableRef>32420</TableRef>
    <Update>
      <FieldName>StatusID</FieldName>
      <OldValue>3</OldValue>
      <NewValue>8</NewValue>
    </Update>
  </Record>
</Task>';


DECLARE @DataBaseName VARCHAR(100)='MyDataBase';
DECLARE @DataBaseSchema VARCHAR(100)='MySchema';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT One.Record.value('order[1]','int')
      ,'UPDATE ' + @DataBaseName + '.' + @DataBaseSchema + '.' + One.Record.value('TableName[1]','varchar(max)') 
        + ' SET ' + One.Record.value('(Update/FieldName)[1]','varchar(max)') + '=''' + One.Record.value('(Update/NewValue)[1]','varchar(max)') + ''' '
        + ' WHERE ' + One.Record.value('KeyField[1]','varchar(max)') + '=''' +  One.Record.value('TableRef[1]','varchar(max)') + ''';'
FROM @x.nodes('/Task/Record') AS One(Record)
```

This is the result:

```
1   UPDATE MyDataBase.MySchema.ProductPerson SET StatusID='8'  WHERE ProductPersonID='32420';
```

Comment: Almost there, but we have to imagine we don't know the exact database and schema location of a table, so we want the code to be able to find it for us and implement it in the xml. In your example, you stated that we know its in 'MyDataBase' and 'MySchema', but imagine if we didn't know that, how can we retrieve it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BruceyBandit Where from should the statement get this information? At which state do you know this? How / from where is this called?

Comment: I have to back out, x-mas, family ... :-) good luck and happy coding.  Please vote up if helpful, thx.

Comment: Cool, I was just about to post it on a separate link but no worries. Thank you for your help, will vote it and try to figure it

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know sql statements run in a specific database, and cannot just jump from one database to another.

Healthy programs usually only use one database to store their data with the tables required.

However, if you still want to work with multiple databases and schemas you can change the connection to the database dynamically, since the database you talk with is chosen at that point.