# using information_schema_tables and concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how can I use the `information_schema_tables` select query to look up `@tablename`, so that, that `table's catalog` and schema is shown, and then concatenate it together so that `@tablename` is displayed as  `table_catalog.table_schema.table name'`?

At the moment I am just calling on the table name using select `@tablename = Value`

```
declare @tablename varchar(MAX)
  declare @tableschema varchar(MAX)
  declare @loop int = 1         

    select  a.* into #tmp
    from 
    (
    select  RID,
    v.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  'Field', 
    v.value('./text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   'Value'        
    from  #XMLTemp
    cross apply Field.nodes ('/Record/*') x(v)
    where v.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  not in ('Update', 'Filter', 'Insert', 'Delete')
    ) as a
    where RID = @loop

    ...

select Table_Catalog, Table_Schema
from Information_Schema.Tables 

...

    select @tablename = ''
    select @tablename = Value
    from #tmp
    where Field='tableName'
    and RID = @loop

    ...

    print 'update ' + @tablename + '

    ...

    select @tablename = Value from #tmp where Field = 'TableName'

    ...

    set @loop = @loop+1
```

Comment: I'm confused... what's wrong with `select Table_Catalog, Table_Schema, Table_Name from Information_Schema.Tables` ? Doesn't that give you the catalog, schema, and table name?

Comment: Please be aware of the fact, that all professionals giving answers on SO are hungry for reputation points. Please vote all helpful answers up and - additionally - mark the best as accepted. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use "+" to concatenate strings.

```
declare @tablename varchar(MAX)
select @tablename = TABLE_CATALOG + '.' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

Keep in mind that if your query returns multiple rows @tablename variable will contains the last value returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select quotename(db_name()) + '.' + quotename( schemas.name ) + '.' + quotename( tables.name ) 
from sys.tables
join sys.schemas on tables.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
```

A couple of notes: "Catalog" in ANSI speak is Database in SQL Server, so within a database it's pretty much a constant value - the name of the current database.

In SQL Server I find the system views are more consistent and reliable than INFORMATION_SCHEMA, which mostly works but has some quirky issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34449786/5089204) I'd like to suggest the following UDF:

You pass in your XML and a catalog's name (or `NULL`or `DEFAULT`) and the same with the schema's name. The function will use `COALESCE` to use the right portion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateUpdateStatement
(
     @XmlData XML
    ,@CatalogName VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    ,@SchemaName VARCHAR(100) = NULL
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal VARCHAR(MAX);

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
    SELECT @RetVal=
              'UPDATE ' 
                     + COALESCE(@CatalogName + '.',TheTable.TABLE_CATALOG + '.', '') 
                     + COALESCE(@SchemaName + '.',TheTable.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.', 'dbo.') 
                     + One.Record.value('TableName[1]','varchar(max)') 
            + ' SET ' + One.Record.value('(Update/FieldName)[1]','varchar(max)') + '=''' + One.Record.value('(Update/NewValue)[1]','varchar(max)') + ''' '
            + ' WHERE ' + One.Record.value('KeyField[1]','varchar(max)') + '=''' +  One.Record.value('TableRef[1]','varchar(max)') + ''';'
    FROM @XmlData.nodes('/Task/Record') AS One(Record) 
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME=One.Record.value('TableName[1]','varchar(max)')
    ) AS TheTable;

    RETURN @RetVal;
END
GO
```

This is how you call it (I used one existing table's name `spz.dbo.AuditRow` in one of my catalogs):

```
DECLARE @x  xml=
'<Task xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Record>
    <order>1</order>
    <TableName>AuditRow</TableName>
    <KeyField>ProductPersonID</KeyField>
    <TableRef>32420</TableRef>
    <Update>
      <FieldName>StatusID</FieldName>
      <OldValue>3</OldValue>
      <NewValue>8</NewValue>
    </Update>
  </Record>
</Task>';

SELECT dbo.CreateUpdateStatement(@x,DEFAULT,DEFAULT);       
--UPDATE spz.dbo.AuditRow SET StatusID='8'  WHERE ProductPersonID='32420';

SELECT dbo.CreateUpdateStatement(@x,'MyCatalog',DEFAULT);   
--UPDATE MyCatalog.dbo.AuditRow SET StatusID='8'  WHERE ProductPersonID='32420';

SELECT dbo.CreateUpdateStatement(@x,DEFAULT,'MySchema');    
--UPDATE spz.MySchema.AuditRow SET StatusID='8'  WHERE ProductPersonID='32420';


SELECT dbo.CreateUpdateStatement(@x,'MyCatalog','MySchema');
--UPDATE MyCatalog.MySchema.AuditRow SET StatusID='8'  WHERE ProductPersonID='32420';
```

You might execute this immediately with

```
EXEC (SELECT dbo.CreateUpdateStatement(@x,NULL,NULL));
```